# Как получить Spring-контекст в объекте класса, который не является бином?

Tags: java, spring, java-ee, spring-mvc

Добрый день!
Есть web-приложение.
AppConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "net.package")
@EnableJpaRepositories("net.package.repository")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

@Autowired
RoleToUserProfileConverter roleToUserProfileConverter;

@Bean(name = "applicationContextProvder")
public ApplicationContextProvider getApplicationContextProvider() {
    return new ApplicationContextProvider();
}

@Bean(name="multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver getResolver() throws IOException {
    CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    //Set the maximum allowed size (in bytes) for each individual file.
    resolver.setMaxUploadSizePerFile(5242880);//5MB
    //You may also set other available properties.
    return resolver;
}

@Override
public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    registry.viewResolver(viewResolver);
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/favicon.ico"). addResourceLocations("/favicon.ico");

}

@Override
public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
    registry.addConverter(roleToUserProfileConverter);
}

@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("messages");
    return messageSource;
}

@Override
public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer matcher) {
    matcher.setUseRegisteredSuffixPatternMatch(true);
}
```

Обычно контекст можно получить так:

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext ctx;
```

Так можно СОЗДАТЬ контекст в классе(не бине):

```
private ApplicationContext context =
        new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class,     HibernateConfiguration.class, MyAppConfigForAsync.class);
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как получить уже созданный при запуске сервера приложений Spring-контекст в объекте класса, который не является бином ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно создать spring-компонент, в который заинжектится spring-контекст в статическую переменную:

```
@Component
public class ApplicationContextHolder {

    // Контекст Spring
    private static ApplicationContext ctx;

    @Autowired
    public ApplicationContextHolder(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        ApplicationContextHolder.ctx = applicationContext;
    }

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return ctx;
    }
}
```

Затем используйте в другом классе:

```
public class NotBean {
    private final ApplicationContext ctx;

    public NotBean() {
        ctx = ApplicationContextHolder.getApplicationContext();
    }
}
```

**Update** - вариант с использованием [ApplicationContextAware](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware.html)

```
@Component
public class ApplicationContextHolder implements ApplicationContextAware {

    // Контекст Spring
    private static ApplicationContext ctx;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        ApplicationContextHolder.ctx = applicationContext;
    }

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return ctx;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо.